# How to compress non-pixelart gifs to mp4?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to convert uploaded gifs to mp4. I know how to do that with ffmpeg. But in some cases people may upload pixel art gifs. Such gifs when converted to mp4 look blurry.
How can I detect gifs which are pixel arts (where pixels cannot be blurry)?

Comment: Where do you intend to play these MP4s?

Comment: @Mulvya On a website inside <video>

Comment: Web MP4s store color with a lower resolution than the full frame size which causes softening of sharp edges. You may be able to mitigate it somehow by upsizing the GIF using a special scaler and then creating the MP4. A bit busy now, will supply command to try later.